# Reactjs- Unable to access class variable inside function in tsx

Tags: reactjs, spfx, tsx

I am unable to access class variable inside a function, following is my code:

```
export class MyClass extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
  public myArray: string[]; //I want to access this variable

  constructor() {
    this.state = { name: "" }
 } 
  private _hello = () => {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.myArray) //this lines throws undefined
  } 
    render(){
      <button onClick={this._hello}>Click</button>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring the function variable outside constructor. Btw render method should be outside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `private` and `public` on react, [here](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/10-typescript-pro-tips-patterns-with-or-without-react-5799488d6680) is some explanation, you could use:

```
const myArray: string[]; //I want to access this variable

export class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    }
  }

  hello = () => {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(myArray) //this lines throws undefined
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.hello}>Click</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @nbi What you want to do with the `myArray`? You could use it inside the hello function too

Comment: this array will be populated by the values which will be coming from other components. As these value does not have any impact on the ui hence I haven't added to the state

Comment: You are right not adding them to states, to transfer data through components, you can use props and get it done